# How can I redirect users to different pages after inserting into the database using Sweet Alert in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am finding it difficult to use the sweet alert after a successful login and also add the sweet alert after a user successfully inserts his/her data into the database. I am finding it difficult to use the sweet alert after a successful login and also add the sweet alert after a user successfully inserts his/her data into the database.x

```js
<?php
        include ("dbcon.php");

        session_start();

        if(isset($_POST['login'])){

            //get the user data
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['username']);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['email']);
            $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['pdf]);
            
            if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pwd)){

                header("Location:../../login.php?loginempty");
                exit();

            }else{

                $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='$email' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn , $select);
                $result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if($result_check < 1){
                    header("Location:../../login.php?invaliduid");
                    exit();

                }else{

                    if($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                        $cpwd = $row['pwd'];
                        
                        //de-hashed the password
                        // $hashedpwd = password_verify($pwd, $row['pdf]);
                        
                        if($pwd != $cpwd){
                            header("Location: ../../login.php?invalidpwd");
                            exit();
        
                        }elseif($pwd == $cpwd){
                            
                            $_SESSION['uid'] =$row['username'];
                            $username = $_SESSION['uid'];

                            echo "
                                Swal.fire({
                                    title: 'Welcome to bottles beach',
                                    text: 'You successfully submitted the form,
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    showCancelButton: false,
                                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                    confirmButtonText: 'Great, show me the site!'
                                }).then((result) => {
                                    if (result.confirmed) {
                                    location = '../../dashboard.php'
                                    }
                                })
                            
                            ";

                            // header("Location:../../dashboard.php?loginsuc");
                            // exit();
                        }
        
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    ?>
    
    
    
    <?php
    session_start();
    include ("dbcon.php");


    if(isset($_POST["reg-btn"])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['email']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['phone']);
        $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['pwd']);
        $cpwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['cpwd']);
        // $verify_token = md5(random());

        // VALIDATION
        if(strlen(trim($pwd)) < 5) {
            // Password Length
            header("Location:../../register.php?passwordshort");
            exit();
        }
        
        if($pwd != $cpwd ) {
            // If Password = Confirm Password
            header("Location:../../register.php?comfirmpass");
            exit();
        }

        // Check for Empty Inputs
        if (empty($username)|| empty($email)|| empty($phone)|| empty($pwd)|| empty($cpwd) ) {

            header ("Location:../../register.php?signupempty");
            exit();

        }else {

            //VALIDATE EMAIL
            if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

                header ("Location:../../register.php?invalidemail");
                exit();

            }else {

                $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND pwd ='$pwd'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn , $select);
                $result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if($result_check > 0) {

                    echo "ooooops!!! user already exists";
                }else {
        
                    $insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, phone, pwd, cpwd) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$phone', '$pwd', '$cpwd')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn , $insert);
        
                    if(!$result) {
        
                        echo "ooooops!!! an error was encountered while inserting data to the database";
                    }else {
        
                        echo "
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Welcome to bottles beach',
                            text: 'You successfully submitted the form,
                            icon: 'success',
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Great, show me the site!'
                        }).then((result) => {
                            if (result.confirmed) {
                            location = '../../login.php'
                            }
                        })
                    
                    ";
                        // header("location: ../../login.php");
                        // exit();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    
    }else {

        header ("Location:../../register.php?signupempty");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

```html
<?php
    $page_title = "Login Form";
    include ('assets/includes/header.php');
    include ('assets/includes/navbar.php');
?>

<div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>Login Form</h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="assets/action/login_action.php" method="POST" autocomplete="no">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Login Now</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    include ('assets/includes/footer.php');
?>







<?php

    $page_title = "Registration Form";
    include ('assets/includes/header.php');
    include ('assets/includes/navbar.php');

    // include ('assets/action/dbcon.php');
?>

<div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>Registration Form With Email Verification</h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="assets/action/code.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label for="cpwd">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="cpwd" id="cpwd" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" name="reg-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Register Now</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
    include ('assets/includes/footer.php');
?>
```

difficult adding sweet alert redirection after a user successfully inserts his / her details

Comment: Can you please include your code and elaborate on what you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Login Now</button>`

try to use javascript code on button click.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#login").click(function()
        {
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "check.php", <--- //your php code for checking credentials
                data: {username:username, password:password},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    swal({
                        title: "Success!",
                        text: "Login Successfully!",
                        type: "success"
                    });
     window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; <--your link to next page
                }, 
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {console.error(xhr);}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```